# jQuery Toggle/change content depending on which link that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website that is going to have a menu. 
In the menu I have two or maybe even three links. 
The links will open a div with a slide effect, next to the menu. (The menu is a right column and the div will open left to it).

So let's say I click link (A). Link (A) opens the div with some text. When I click link (A) again, the div will disappear. 
So, the same logic for link (B), but instead it will show a gallery. That's not the important part.

I want to be able to toggle between the information inside the div. 
If I click link (B) while the div is still open with the information from link (A), I just want the div to switch the content, NOT close and re-open.

Basically - if I click the same link that opened the div, it will disappear. But if I click the other link, the content should just change.

Any suggestions?

Here's the div:

```
    <div class="col-md-2" id="openInfo">
    <div id="info"> <p>INFO</p></div>

    <div id="images">
        <p>IMAGES</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

The Links:

```
    <a href="#openInfo" id="treatInfo">TREATMENT INFO</a>

    <a href="#openInfo" id="gallery" >GALLERY</a>
```

The Script:

```
  $("#gallery").click(function () {
    $("#openInfo").toggleClass("open");
    $("#images").css("display", "block");
    $("#info").css("display", "none");
});


$("#treatInfo").click(function () {
    $("#openInfo").toggleClass("open");
    $("#info").css("display", "block");
    $("#images").css("display", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a check when to toggle the `open` class, meaning that when that condition is not true the `.open` class will not be toggled (and remain as is):

```
$("#gallery").click(function () {
    if (!$("#openInfo").is(".open") || $("#images").is(":visible")) {
        $("#openInfo").toggleClass("open");
    }
    $("#images").css("display", "block");
    $("#info").css("display", "none");
});


$("#treatInfo").click(function () {
    if (!$("#openInfo").is(".open") || $("#info").is(":visible")) {
        $("#openInfo").toggleClass("open");
    }
    $("#info").css("display", "block");
    $("#images").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I've been looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional properties in your **div** to know if you should replace content or close. For example "data content"

```
<div id="myDiv" data-content="images">
    <p>IMAGES</p>
</div>
```

Using jQuery you can retrieve that property using:

```
$('#myDiv').attr('data-content');
```

Also you can set a value using:

```
$('#myDiv').attr('data-content','images');
$('#myDiv').attr('data-content','info');
```

This way, you can know if you should replace the content or close the div:

```
$("#treatInfo").click(function () {
    if($('#myDiv').attr('data-content') == 'info'){
        // close div
    }else{
        $('#myDiv').attr('data-content','info');
        // load info content
    }
});
```